# Как изменится расстояние от точки А до точки Б в двумерной системе, если точку А сдвинуть на (а,б)?

Tags: математика

Не могу упростить многочлен :)

В общем есть точка А(x1,y1) и есть точка Б(x2,y2). Расстояние между ними

= `sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)`

вопрос, а если я точку а передвину в точку со сдвигом (a,b), как изменится это расстояние?

Решение сводится к дроби

`sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2) / sqrt((x2-(x1+a))^2 + (y2-(y1+b))^2)`, но я не могу ее упростить (то есть привести это отношение к зависимости от `a` и `b`, хотя расстояние ведь не зависит от начальных координат.

Уточнение для ответа. Если расстоянием до сдвига было С, то после сдвига расстоянием должна быть `С*F(a,b)`, то есть я хочу зависимость, в которой не будет начальных координат, ведь реально от них изменение расстояния не зависит

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что вы подразумеваете точка А будет иметь координаты(x1+a,y1+ b) ?

Comment: @ivanK. правильно заметил, ответ кажется будет `=sqrt((x2+a-x1)^2 + (y2+b-y1)^2)`

Comment: @Saidolim, это разве ответ?

Comment: @iRumba, вы не правы, то о чем вы говорите без координат начала и конца невозможно будет рассчитать как изменилось расстояние. Уменьшилось, увеличилось, или осталось неизменным.

Comment: @iRumba, а упростить можно будет только загнав под один корень всё выражение и раскрыв скобки, возможно удастся как-нибудь упростить, но зависимость от x1,y1,x2,y2 у вас останется.

Comment: @ivanK., как же невозможно? Допустим точка А имеет координаты 0,0 а точка Б - (5,3). Это будет равносильно точкам (1,1) (6,4), а так же точкам (29,81) и (34,84). И если я сдвину первую точку на (1,1), то и изменение для всех трех случаев будет одинаковым

Comment: @Saidolim, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/457080/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Имеем A(0,0) и B(0,5) расстояние = 5

Имеем A(0,0) и B(3,4) расстояние = 5

в обоих случаях передвигаем A на (0,1)

получаем

Имеем A'(0,1) и B(0,5) расстояние = 4

Имеем A'(0,1) и B(3,4) расстояние = sqrt(9+9) = 3*sqrt(2) = рациональное число

не зная координат ОБЕИХ точек изменения расстояния тоже не узнать

а верный ответ нам подсказал [Saidolim](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/182317/saidolim)  **sqrt((x2+a-x1)^2 + (y2+b-y1)^2)**

**для одномерного случая (тех кто в танке)**

A(1) B(5) => R=4

A(5) B(1) => R=4,

сдвигаем A в обоих случаях на 1, расстояние тоже получаем

A(2) B(5) => R=3 => dR = -1

A(6) B(1) => R=5 => dR = 1

из высшей математики мы узнаём, что 1≠-1

**Случай с вектором (для особо настырных)**

Есть вектор A(x,y) есть смещение (x', y')

тогда R=корень(x^2+y^2) R'=корень((x+x')^2+(y+y')^2)

dR=R-R', т.е. мы опять приходим к ответу [Saidolim](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/182317/saidolim) , где x=x2-x1 и y=y2-y1, в случае с двумя точками

Comment: **A(1) B(5) => R=4** или **A(5) B(1) => R=4**, сдвигаем A в обоих случаях на 1, расстояние тоже получаем разное

Comment: Перейдем от двумерной системы к одномерной. Есть А(1) и Б(5). Расстояние между ними равно С = |Б.х - А.х| = |5-1| = 4. Теперь сдвигаю точку А в точку (3). dx = 2. Новое расстояние будет равно Сновое = С - dx = 2.

Comment: а теперь перейдите к математике в точке :D

Comment: хорошо, согласен. А что, если допустить, что мы измеряем не расстояние, а вектор. Ну или как там. Тогда для случая 2 5 оно будет положительным, а для 6 1 отрицательным.

Comment: Не понял Вас, что значит **положительным отрицательным**, вы длину вектора чтоль измерить стараетесь или что?  "мы измеряем не расстояние, а вектор" объясните мне формулировку **измеряем вектор**

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/457080/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD

Comment: @iRumba Вот кстати насчет вектора могу подкинуть идею. Если очень хочется пересчитывать расстояние, не запоминая координат начала и конца, запоминайте координаты вектора AB. Вот если эти проекции пересчитать на величину сдвига, то модуль полученного вектора и есть новое расстояние

Answer (score 0):

В соответствии с формулой косинусов,
**A<sub>1</sub>B<sup>2</sup> = AA<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> +  AB<sup>2</sup> - 2 AA<sub>1</sub> * AB * cos(AA<sub>1</sub>, AB)**.
При этом **cos(AA<sub>1</sub>, AB) = scal_prod(AA<sub>1</sub>,AB)/(AA<sub>1</sub>*AB)**
scal_prod - скалярное произведение векторов.