# Как при перемещении точки в географических координатах, вычислить новое расстояние?

Tags: математика, gps

Есть точка А(ш,д) и точка Б(ш,д). Мы знаем расстояние между ними (с единичным радиусом), вычисленное по формуле

`arccos( sin(д1)*sin(д2) + cos(д1)*cos(д2)*cos(ш2-ш1))`.

Далее я сдвигаю точку А. Теперь, чтобы вычислить новое расстояние, нужно снова просчитывать 6 тригонометрических функций. И я вот думаю, а не проще ли будут расчеты, если новое расстояние считать, зная старые координаты и новые координаты? Помогите составить формулу

Comment: Я думаю, вы экономите на спичках. Проще формула не будет (она не проще даже на плоскости, а уж на сфере и подавно), а тригонометрические функции типа косинуса — одна инструкция процессора.

Comment: @VladD, я тоже так думаю. Но вдруг бы это сократило формулу с 6 функций до 3х. Далее умножаем на количество вычисленных расстояний... В общем попытаться стоило )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A(x1,y1,z1), B(x2,y2,z2), и dA(dx, dy, dz)

**!!A и B вычисляются переводом сферических координат в декартову!!**

старое расстояние R1=Корень(квадрат(x1-x2)+квадрат(y1-y2)+квадрат(z1-z2))

новое расстояние R2=Корень(квадрат(x1-x2+dx)+квадрат(y1-y2+dy)+квадрат(z1-z2+dz))

разница расстояний dR = R2-R1;

прочитайте про перевод из сферических координат в декартову [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82), и будет Вам счастье

По другому никак

**UPD:**

Есть вектор A(ϴa,φa), Вектор B(ϴb,φb), и вектор A2(ϴa+dϴ,φa+dφ)

они же в декартовой системе A(Xa,Ya,Za) B(Xb,Yb,Zb),

Где Xi=sin(ϴi)*cos(φi), Yi=sin(ϴi)*sin(φi), Zi=cos(ϴi)

Найдем угол между ними αab=ArcCos(ab'/(a'*b'))

где ab'=Xa*Xb+Ya*Yb+Za*Zb, a'=Корень(Xa^2+Ya^2+Za^2), b'=Корень(Xb^2+Yb^2+Zb^2)

и длинну дуги Lab=αab*R

т.е. примерно так:

```
public double GetSphereSectorLen(double ϴ1,double φ1,double ϴ2,double φ2, double R)
{
  double X1=Math.Sin(ϴ1)*Math.Cos(φ1);
  double Y1=Math.Sin(ϴ1)*Math.Sin(φ1);
  double Z1=Math.Cos(ϴ1);
  double X2=Math.Sin(ϴ2)*Math.Cos(φ2);
  double Y2=Math.Sin(ϴ2)*Math.Sin(φ2);
  double Z2=Math.Cos(ϴ2);
  double ab_=X1*X2+Y1*Y2+Z1*Z2;
  double a_=Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(X1,2)+Math.Pow(Y1,2)+Math.Pow(Z1,2));
  double b_=Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(X2,2)+Math.Pow(Y2,2)+Math.Pow(Z2,2));
  double αab=Math.Acos(ab_/(a_*b_));
  return αab*R;
}

double LAB=GetSphereSectorLen(ϴa,φa,ϴb,φb);
double LA2B=GetSphereSectorLen(ϴa+dϴ,φa+dφ,ϴb,φb);
double dL = LAB-LA2B;
```

Comment: В данной задаче уже нет x и y и расстояние вычисляется иначе

Comment: ответил в посте

Comment: А вообще вы зря взялись за такую задачу с Вашими знаниями линейной алгебры (судя по предыдущему посту)

Comment: Меня никто не спрашивал, хочу я за нее браться или нет. Заодно заполню дыры в знаниях. По крайней мере теперь знаю для чего все это преподавалось, а значит будет веселее ))

Comment: Теперь вопрос. Если я переведу свои точки в декартову систему координат, то расстояния я буду получать неверные таким способом, потому что буду получать не длины дуг, а длины их проекций )

Comment: Никто не умеет ходить сквозь планету ))

Comment: дык надож описывать задачу полностью, и перемещение у вас, звените будет не dX, dY, dZ, а dθ, dφ, и искать вам надо [дугу окружности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Дуга_окружности), а не расстояние между точками, что является корнем сумм квадратов разностей координат. Формулируйте задачу правильно

Comment: Сегодня не успею ответить, только в ПН. Надеюсь кто-то меня опередит...